# Capybara::ElementNotFound - navbar item in toggled navbar

Tags: rspec, navbar, bootstrap-5, capybara, headless-browser

I am testing elements in my navbar, and it currently fails to recognise an item.
I first checked with save_and_open_page, and the page really looked correct, so I could not understand why my test failed.
Then I checked with save_and_open_screenshot, and saw to my surprise that the navbar was collapsed and I only saw the hamburger menu. So it made sense that the test failed.
But how to handle this? Why did it render a collapsed navbar?

Could this be due to running the specs in a headless browser? The strange thing is that these tests used to run, and I can't see what change caused this to fail now.

My spec:

```
# frozen_string_literal: true

feature "Users can view their data", js: true do
  let!(:user) { create(:user) }

  before do
    login_as(user)
    visit root_path
  end

  scenario "with valid credentials" do
    click_link t(:user_profile)

    fill_in t("activerecord.attributes.user.email"), with: user.email
    fill_in t("activerecord.attributes.user.password"), with: "password"
    click_button t(:update)

    expect(page).to have_content(t("activerecord.attributes.user.username"))
    expect(page).to have_content(t("activerecord.attributes.user.email"))
    expect(page).to have_content(t("activerecord.attributes.user.password"))
  end
end
```

My rendered HTML:

```
   <div class='collapse navbar-collapse' id='navbarSupportedContent'>
            <ul class='navbar-nav mr-auto'>
                <li class='nav-item active'>
                    <a class='nav-link' href='#'>

                        Home
                        <span class='sr-only'>(current)</span>
                    </a>
                </li>
                <li class='nav-item'>
                    <a class='nav-link' href='/pages/about'>About</a>
                </li>
                <li class='nav-item'>
                    <a class='nav-link' href='/users/edit'>Mijn profiel</a>
                </li>
                <li class='nav-item'>
                    <a class="nav-link" rel="nofollow" data-method="delete" href="/users/sign_out">Log uit</a>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </div>
```

Comment: I'm not sure about the headless browser being the source of the issue. But, one sure way to find out is to run the tests locally in an actual browser.

Comment: This could also just be a timing issue. I haven't used Capybara in a long time. But, from what I recall, it's not good at handling timing issues. I remember having to pepper my specs with sleep statements to try to ensure that the async javascript action completed before the next line in the spec.

Comment: Hi @aridlehoover, thanks for helping. I just did run the spec without the headless browser (with a headfull browser?) and it passed.

Comment: Btw, I see that when I resize my screen, and the hamburger appears, that the hamburger is not working. When I click it, nothing happens. Maybe that also explains why the test is failing. Let's see if I can fix that.

Comment: Problem solved. I still used the old bootstrap classes, without 'br' in the name. That made the hamburger working, and the test now passes

Comment: Typo above, I meant without '_bs_' in the name